# Entity Framework 6: is it possible to update specific object property without getting the whole object?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an object with several really large string properties. In addition, it has a simple timestamp property.

What I trying to achieve is to update only timestamp property without getting the whole huge object to the server.

Eventually, I would like to use EF and to do in the most performant way something equivalent to this:

```
update [...]
set [...] = [...]
where [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the following, you can update a single column:

```
  var yourEntity = new YourEntity() { Id = id, DateProp = dateTime };
  using (var db = new MyEfContextName())
  {
    db.YourEntities.Attach(yourEntity);
    db.Entry(yourEntity).Property(x => x.DateProp).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: I tried your proposed solution, it doesn't works for me. The string fields in my question above are 'required'. So, when I create empty object with id and timestamp only, it fails during 'SaveChanges' and complains about missing required fields. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I managed to handle this. The solution is the same as proposed by Seany84, with the only addition of disabling validation, in order to overcome issue with required fields. Basically, I had to add the following line just before 'SaveChanges():

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

So, the complete solution is:

```
  var yourEntity = new YourEntity() { Id = id, DateProp = dateTime };
  using (var db = new MyEfContextName())
  {
    db.YourEntities.Attach(yourEntity);
    db.Entry(yourEntity).Property(x => x.DateProp).IsModified = true;
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
```